# change video src in javascript w/Parcel

Tags: javascript, path, parceljs

I use a Parcel bundler and I would like to change the video src with javascript dynamically like this:

video.src = './assets/video/1.mp4'

What is the correct path to bundle the video file into the dist folder?

The video file is in assets/video folder.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It works with require such as:

video.src = require('../assets/video/1.mp4')